# Booting keeps on going forever. Unable to load the os on my laptop

Tags: boot, grub2, google-chrome, root, downloads

A few days back, I was trying to download a [zip file](https://ai4bharat.iitm.ac.in/samanantar) which is of size ~6GB. I tried downloading it using google-chrome and after downloading for about 60%, it failed. Later I also tried to download it using `wget` and `curl` and it was also getting terminated mid way. I remember a notification popping up in my notification-tray saying "the volume filesystem root has only 800 MB disk space remaining..." (i don't remember the exact message). After I was done for the day, I turned off my laptop. Next day, when i tired to turn on my laptop, the booting wouldn't end (I tried a few times).

So, I though i should boot it using a pen-drive I created a bootable `ubuntu 20.04 LTS` drive and booted through it. Later, I clicked on "Try ubuntu" after it was done. I then, clicked on "Other locations" in the Files on the sidebar. Here I can see all the data I have in my system. The location where I can see the data for my laptop is `admin:///media/ubuntu/2f07coe4-23bybhdf-sdsj/`. This folder contains `var`, `usr`, `tmp`, `sys`, `root` and folder like that. I was wondering

Question: Can I get to the location which is required for booting my laptop normally and free up some space by deleting the files.Once that is done, I'll be able to use my laptop normally. Also, I'm wondering if the assumption is right or not.

Edit

Laptop model : HP Pavilion 15 Notebook PC

BIOS version : F.42

Total memory : 4 GB

OS           : Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, AMD 64 Desktop

UPDATE

I checked the free space on my laptop using

> df -h

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       916G  869G  551M 100% /
```

So, I deleted some video and data files from content inside folder /media/ubuntu/ and then tried again.

Finally, I was able to boot it successfully.

Comment: The "location which is required for booting" will be the main partition for your Ubuntu installation. You will want to have at least 10% of its storage free, and ideally a bit more than that.

Comment: I want to fix the installed system. When, i press power on button of my laptop, the loading screen doesn't move further.

Comment: This report will tell us more about your system. Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version over somewhat older ISO with your USB installer  or any working install.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/